# How do I set the z-index of a Wordpress navigation sub-menu?

Tags: css, wordpress, z-index

I'm configurating [this website](http://www.investech.com.br).

When I put the cursos at `Sobre`, in the navigation menu, the sub-menu appears cropped.

[image]

I know that I can solve this problem by using `z-index:9999`.

```css
right_selector {
    z-index:9999;
}
```

But I can't find the right selector.

I've opened the page using my browser, used 'inspect element' to find the right selector. Here's a list of a few selector that I've tried but didn't worked.

```css
#menu-item-345 > ul

#menu-item-345 > ul > li

#sub-menu toggle-submenu li
```

How can I fix this problem? Which selector should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z index is not your issue. Your issue is that your menus always expand to the right, and you are hiding overflow. The submenu for the last child in the main menu should expand left, not right.

Write a css definition for the last child on the parent UL that expands the submenu the opposite way.

Comment: How am I supposed to `"Write a css definition for the last child on the parent UL that expands the menu the opposite way."` ? By your answer, i've changed `.primary-navigation{float: right;}` to `.primary-navigation{float: left;}`. Now it works! My text appears completly. But I think this wasn't what you were thinking when you wrote your answer... right? Can you explain which selector I'm supposed to change?

Comment: `How am I supposed to "Write a css definition for the last child on the parent UL that expands the menu the opposite way." `

well, you kinda did it - not exactly as I envisioned, but if simply changing the float on the entire nav works, then go with it!

Comment: It worked but if you enter the website, you'll see that the container-box still cropped. Anyway... it worked x-) Thanks mate!!

Comment: If instead of floating the entire container element - try just floating the last submenu item left and leave all the others floating right. That should fix the weird box cutoff. Honestly I am at work right now so I don't have time to write it for you - but if you are unable to figure it out I can take a deeper look tonight to determine the exact markup changes required.